# Find a divergent sequence $\{X_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|X_{n+m}-X_n|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers

> **Question.** Find a divergent sequence $\{X_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|X_{n+m}-X_n|=0$$

I don't really know, if someone could walk me through this it'd be really appreciated.
Edit: I'm dumb af ignore what I said before I deleted it. lmao

Comment: $x_n=1/n^{1/2}$ is not a divergent sequence, so it cannot be a counter-example in the first place.

Comment: $\log n$ should do the trick, or any $n^a$ where $0<a<1$

Comment: One idea is to take a 'slowly increasing function' $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, in the sense that $f(x)$ itself grows to infinity but its growth speed $f'(x)$ decreases to $0$, and then take $x_n=f(n)$. Examples of such function include $f(x)=\log x$ or $f(x)=x^a$ for $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: $a_n=\ln n$ is an example.

Answer (score 2):

$X_n= \ln(n)$.

Then, for each $m$ you have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|X_{n+m}-X_n| =\lim_{n\to\infty}|\ln(\frac{m+n}{n}) |= \lim_{n\to\infty}|\ln(1+\frac{m}{n}) | = \ln(1)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n= 1+ {1 \over 2} + \cdots + {1 \over n}$, then $x_n \to \infty$.

For any $m$, we see that
$x_{n+m} - x_n = {1 \over n+1} + \cdots + {1 \over n+m} \le {m \over n}$, hence
$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+m} - x_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n=\sqrt{n}$ then we have
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+m}-\sqrt{n})
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{m}n}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\left(1+\frac{m}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)-1\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{m}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{m}{2\sqrt{n}}+o\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)\\
&=0\\
\end{align}$$
and clearly $X_n$ is divergent. Any strictly increasing concave function should work for $X_n$.

Comment: Quicker argument is $$\sqrt{n+m}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{n+m}+\sqrt{n}}\to 0$$ as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: @szw1710 Yes that is much better! Oops.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another type of counter-example.

Let $x_n = \sin \big(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{n}\big)$. Then $x_n$ does not converge since $x_n$ oscillates. This is easily seen by noting that the values of $(x_n)$ at odd squares are given by $x_{(2n+1)^2} = (-1)^n$. On the other hand, by the mean-value theorem,

$$ \left| x_{n+m} - x_n \right| \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \left| \sqrt{n+m} - \sqrt{n} \right| = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{m}{\sqrt{n+m} + \sqrt{n}}, $$

hence the difference $\left| x_{n+m} - x_n \right|$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each fixed $m$.

Comment: @Surb, That was a huge typo :( I fixed it now.